Finding $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } n^{-2} \exp(-tn^{-2})$
Is there a closed expression for the following sum with $t>1$?
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } n^{-2} \exp(-tn^{-2})$$
Related work:

Replacing sum with integral:
$$\int _{n=1}^{\infty } n^{-2} \exp(-tn^{-2})di=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)}{2 \sqrt{t}}$$

Replacing sum with integral and $(1-x)\approx \exp(-x)$ sub:


$$\int_1^{\infty } n^{-2} \left(1-n^{-2}\right)^t = \frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (t+1)}{2 \Gamma \left(t+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$

Euler-Maclaurin formula from here
$$\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^t=\int_1^k\frac{1}{x^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^t dx +\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{k^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)^t +...$$

Related generating functions
$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty } x^{-2} \left(u-x^{-2} \right)^{-1}=\frac{\sqrt{u}-\pi  \cot \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{u}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{u}}$$
$$\int_{x=1}^{\infty } x^{-2} \left(u-x^{-2} \right)^{-1}=\frac{\coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{u}\right)}{\sqrt{u}}$$


$$\sum _{x=1}^{\infty } x^{-2} (u-x)^{-1}=\frac{\pi ^2 u+6 \psi ^{(0)}(1-u)+6 \gamma }{6 u^2}$$
$$\int _{x=1}^{\infty } x^{-2} (u-x)^{-1}=\frac{u+\log (1-u)}{u^2}$$
$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty } x^{-2} \exp (-t x)=\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-t}\right)$$
$$\int_{x=1}^{\infty } x^{-2}\exp (-t x)=e^{-t}-t \Gamma (0,t)$$
Notebook

What have you tried?

Also are you even sure that the series converges?

@Kraken updated the post with some of the things I tried (dead-ends)

I doubt there's a closed form for the series : $$\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{\exp \left(-\frac{t}{j^2}\right)}{j^2}=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left\frac{\pi  \coth \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{s}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{s}}\right=\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^m t^m
\zeta (2 (1+m))}{m!}=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x , 0F_2\left(;1,\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{4} \left(t x^2\right)\right)}{-1+e^x} , dx=\int{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{i e^{\frac{4 t}{(-i+2 x)^2}} \tanh (\pi
x)}{2 \left(\frac{1}{2}+i x\right)^2} , dx$$

@MariuszIwaniuk Where did these 4 subexpressions come from? Any chance you can share your Mathematica code for this as an answer here?

using: $\zeta (n)=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{-1+n}}{\left(-1+e^x\right) \Gamma (n)} , dx$ we have: $\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^m t^m \zeta (2+2 m)}{m!}=\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^m t^m \int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{1+2 m}}{\left(-1+e^x\right) \Gamma (2+2 m)} ,
dx}{m!}=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x , _0F_2\left(;1,\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{4} \left(t x^2\right)\right)}{-1+e^x} , dx$

Another: $$\int_0^{\infty } -, _0F_2\left(;\frac{1}{2},1;-\frac{1}{4} \left(t x^2\right)\right) \ln \left(1-e^{-x}\right) ,
dx=\int_0^1 \frac{, _0F_2\left(;1,\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{4} t \ln ^2(x)\right) \ln (x)}{-1+x} , dx=\int_0^1 \frac{i \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}\left(\frac{2 \pi  \sqrt{t}}{\ln
\left(\frac{-1+x}{x}\right)}\right)}{2 \sqrt{t}} , dx=\int_1^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{t}{x^2}} \left(-t+x^2\right) \left(\pi  (-1+2 x)-i \ln \left(1-e^{-2 i \pi  x}\right)+i \ln
\left(1-e^{2 i \pi  x}\right)\right)}{\pi  x^5} , dx$$

I unfortunately can't see this formula in comments as its too long, and can't copy/paste it, I wonder if you could post it as an answer

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Assuming that the series converges
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \exp(-\frac{t}{n^2})&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \Big(\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-t/n^2)^j}{j!}\Big)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \Big(\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j(t^j)}{n^{2j}j!}\Big)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^j(t^j)}{n^{2j+2}j!}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^j(t^j)}{n^{2j+2}j!}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^j(t^j)}{j!}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{2j+2}}\Big)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^j(t^j)}{j!}\zeta(2j+2)\\
\end{align*}
I doubt this will be useful, but if you consider a Poisson random variable $X$, then you can rewrite
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \exp(-\frac{t}{n^2})=e^t\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j\zeta(2j+2) e^{-t}\frac{(t^j)}{j!}$$
$$=e^t\mathbb E[(-1)^X\zeta(2(X+1))].$$
